# Program type already present when generating signed apk

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies

Program type already present: `packagename.BuildConfig`

When i try to generate signed apk for live my application i getting error like :`Program type already present: packagename.BuildConfig`

Code run successfully but signed apk not generate.

**Here is my gradle file**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "packegename"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner 
   "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

   compileOptions {
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
   }
   buildTypes {
    release {
        lintOptions {
            checkReleaseBuilds false
            abortOnError false
        }
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard- 
      android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
     }
  }
  configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    }}
  }
  dependencies {
  implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
 //noinspection GradleCompatible
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
 implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint- 
 layout:1.1.3'
 implementation "com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0"
  implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
 implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
 testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
 implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
 implementation 'com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.1.21'
 implementation 'com.android.support:percent:28.0.0'
 implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
 implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.9.6'
 implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:extension- 
rtmp:2.9.6'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.26.0'
implementation 'com.gmail.samehadar:iosdialog:1.0'
implementation 'com.wonderkiln:camerakit:0.13.1'
implementation 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.2.0'
implementation 'net.the4thdimension:audio-wife:1.0.3'
implementation 'com.github.MasayukiSuda:GPUVideo-android:v0.1.0'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.mindorks.android:prdownloader:0.4.0'
implementation 'com.akexorcist:RoundCornerProgressBar:2.0.3'
implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
implementation 'jp.co.cyberagent.android:gpuimage:2.0.3'
implementation project(path: ':liveVideoBroadcasterSDK')
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation'com.android.support.
test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Code run successfully but when i build release apk i got this error:

**AGPBI:**

```
{
  "kind": "error",
  "text": "Program type already present: packagename.BuildConfig",
  "sources": [
    {

    }
  ],
  "tool": "D8"
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am also getting "Program type already present" issue while generating Signed APK.Please help me on this.